# UIScrollView Not scrolling to the bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a scrollview set up that holds 20 sunglasses, when calling the function, it brings up a new view with the sunglasses 2 by 2 with 20 in total (with 19 and 20 being at the bottom of the scrollview).
It works perfectly on iPhone & iPhone5 but on the iPad, it only goes to 16, if I try and drag further, I can see the remaining 4 sunglasses, but I cannot select them, as the scrollview just bounces back to the 'bottom' which it thinks is 16.

This is on an iPad Air, so I am not sure if it an iPad 2 would have this issue with the different resolution.

This is how I am calling the view;

```
- (IBAction)glassesClick:(id)sender
{
    [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] playSoundEffect:1];
    [scroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 5) animated:NO];

    glassesView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:glassesView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^
     {
         glassesView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
     } completion:nil];
}
```

Scroll container view setting;

```
{
    for(UIView *view in [scroll subviews])
        [view removeFromSuperview];

    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, 1760);

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int xCoord = 0;
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            xCoord = 57;
        else
            xCoord = 188;


        UIButton *glasss = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord, 20 + i/2 * 150 + i/2 * 20, 75, 150)];

        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            int xCoord = 0;
            if(i % 2 == 0)
                xCoord = 156;
            else
                xCoord = 462;

            glasss.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord, 20 + i/2 * 300 + i/2 * 20, 150, 300);
            scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, 2580);
        }

        glasss.tag = i + 1;
        [glasss addTarget:self action:@selector(glassChosen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [glasss setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"glass%d.png", i + 1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[glasss imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

        if(i >= 10)
        {
            if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"purchased_glasses"] isEqualToString:@"NO"])
            {
                UIImageView *locked = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 25)];
                locked.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lock_button.png"];
                [glasss addSubview:locked];
                [locked release];

                [glasss removeTarget:self action:@selector(glassChosen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [glasss addTarget:self action:@selector(chooseLockedFlavor) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            }
        }

        UIImageView *backGlass = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:glasss.frame];
        backGlass.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_glass.png"];
        [backGlass setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [scroll addSubview:backGlass];
        [backGlass release];

        [scroll addSubview:glasss];
        [glasss release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have autolayout turned on? You probably need to set the contentSize of your scrollview.

Comment: Hi, I have added the rest of the code to show the scrollview container

Comment: `scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, 1760);` you're explicitly setting the height of the contentSize. As such, you're probably blocking your iPad view. Try setting it dynamically (or not setting it at all?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this segment:

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, 1760);
```

We discovered you're explicitly setting the height of the contentSize. As such, you're probably blocking your iPad view. Try setting it dynamically (or not setting it at all!).

Answer (score 0):

Set `scrollView` `contentSize` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        scroll.contentSize = CGSize(scroll.frame.size.width, 1760)
    }
```